# a question about source in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I have a file named test7.tcl:

```
namespace eval ::dai {
   variable name "ratzip"
   variable birthday "1982"
   proc hello {} {
      variable name
      variable birthday
      puts "Hello, I am $name birthday is $birthday"
   }
}
```

and I want to source this file into another file, called test8.tcl in this way:

```
source test7.tcl

::dai::hello
```

but it gives me error: couldn't read file "test7.tcl": no such file or directory

but the two files are under the same folder, what happened?

Comment: I bet you're not running test8.tcl like this: `tclsh test8.tcl` or `source test8.tcl`. Instead, you're in a different directory so the filename isn't what you expect. Diagnose with `file normalize test7.tcl` to see if the full filename is what you expect.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To source a file that is in the same directory as the currently executing script, use this:

```
source [file join [file dirname [info script]] "test7.tcl"]
```

Note that this *doesn't* work inside procedures defined inside the outer script (test8.tcl in your case) because they're typically called after the source finishes. If that's the case for you, the simplest fix is to just save the output of `info script` in a variable in your outer script (or just source all files immediately instead of lazily for the ultimately best approach).

Answer (score 5):

Use `source [file join [file dirname [info script]] test7.tcl]` -- that way you'll be sourcing the target file by its full pathname constructed from the full pathname of the file executing `source`; this will work no matter what your current directory is during the execution.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to specify the path of the file to be sourced relative to the path of `test8.tcl` but relative to the *current working directory*. E.g. use the absolute path:

```
source /path/to/test7.tcl
```