# How can I source a tcl file?

Tags: tcl, ns2

I created a `tcl` file in a directory and I want to source another `tcl` file located not in a same directory.

The first file is in the `/home/ubuntu/ns/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35`, the second one is in the `/home/ubuntu/ns/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/indep-utils/cmu-scen-gen/setdest`.

I want to execute `:source "home/ubuntu/ns/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/indep-utils/cmu-scen-gen/setdest/mob.tcl"`.

As soon as I do this, I get the following error:

`couldn't read file "home/ubuntu/ns/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/indep-utils/cmu-scen-gen/setdest/mob.tcl": no such file or directory
while executing "source.orig home/ubuntu/ns/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/indep-utils/cmu-scen-gen/setdest/mob.tcl"
("uplevel" body line 1)`

Comment: I see a link at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9275098/how-to-run-tcl-script-in-other-tcl-script.  One more, I see your code, it seems missing the root /. It can be [:source "/home/ubuntu/ns/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/indep-utils/cmu-scen-gen/setdest/mob.tcl"]

Comment: One old question [about source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508453/a-question-about-source-in-tcl), may be help you.

Comment: thanks @VinhCC . I added the root / and it executed correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run tcl script in other tcl script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9275098/how-to-run-tcl-script-in-other-tcl-script)

Comment: If answered, why not provide an actual answer and accept it?

Answer (score 0):

I use  `:source "/home/ubuntu/ns/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/indep-utils/cmu-scen-gen/setdest/mob.tcl"`
and it executed correctly.

Comment: The usual suggestion is to make a copy of `mob.tcl` to the folder with the simulation, and simply use this line in the simulation : `source "./mob.tcl"`